# How to feed location data from Twitter's streaming API into google maps

Tags: google-maps, twitter, socket.io, geocoding

I'm building a twitter app on node and socket.io that should display the locations of streaming twitter data on a google map in real time. I'm having trouble figuring out the best way to grab the location from the Twitter Streaming API. The API has a coordinates attribute, but only 1-2% of all tweets have this data available, which kind of defeats the point of what I'm doing. There's also a location attribute for each user, which seems more promising. Given that user input/format is unpredictable, my current solution is to manually create a hash of US states/major cities with coordinates (in geo json- to feed to google maps) and reg ex to match with the user's location strings. Does anybody know of a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [filter for the Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#locations) which will *only* show you Tweets which have location information.

I assume, from your question, that you're only interested in messages from within the continental USA?

In which case, add the following parameter to your streaming request

`locations=24.431150,-123.574219,47.683144,-59.238281`

That's roughly the bounding box - you can adjust as you see fit.